# Asp.net core 2.2 TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream'

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-2.2

I am receiving error:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream' from assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

When I trying to referring method in asp.net core 2.2(VS 2019) application from .NET 4.6  (VS 2015) framework class library (the actual method has referred `System.Data.SqlTypes` for reading stream data)

It works fine if tried to referred in MVC application(framework 4.6).
So it is not an issue with method and am suspecting it might be compatible issue with .NET core 2.2.

Please find below code In .NET framework 4.6 class library which was used in .net core 2.2

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
```

```
void method()
{
   **SqlFileStream sqlFileStream = new SqlFileStream(filePath, transactionContext, FileAccess.Read);**
    byte[] data = new byte[sqlFileStream.Length];
    sqlFileStream.Read(data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(sqlFileStream.Length));

    sqlFileStream.Position = 0;

    msgStream = new MemoryStream();
    sqlFileStream.CopyTo(msgStream);

    sqlFileStream.Close();
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: sir, are to try to save file in ms sql database?

Comment: Nope...Actually file stored in sql as stream. It class help me to retrieve file stream from sql

Comment: Actual issue with system.data.SqlType not compatible with .Net core 2.2

Comment: are you using entity framework core? if you are using i can share code. by which you can access file from stream from ms sql database in asp.net core.

Comment: FYI, I just referring method which was coded in Framework 4.6 class Library. Not in position to modified the class library files. only issue was getting above error when I referring method from .net core 2.2 framework( Note: Class library add reference) because referring method was using SqlFileStream So that .net core can't load System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Microsoft.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream` in `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`, `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` is the one of the new libraries that Microsoft separated of .Net Framework.

[Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/5.0.0-preview2.22096.2)